# Неправильно отображение англ раскладки при удаленном доступе к компьютеру

Tags: intellij-idea, шрифты, mac

Все привет, кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, при удаленном использовании компьютера на windows ( через Mac) конкретно в IDEA вместо английской раскладки отображается вот такие символы , причем в остальных программах и текстовых редакторах все отлично[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю переустановить пробовали? какая версия ide?

Comment: налицо русская секция UTF-8 отображаемая в кодировке CP1251

Comment: Версия Community 2020.2 , да перестанавливал, не помогло.

Comment: так а что делать то в итоге с кодировкой и где стоит ее менять?